# Creating Pages Dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

The following is my code where i am updating the content of the dynamically created pages constantly but the problem is my update function is running every 3 seconds on pages that i am not even viewing. i am not able to fix this.

```
var widgetNames = new Array();
var widgetId = new Array();



$( document ).on( "pagecreate", function() {
    $( "body > [data-role='panel']" ).panel().enhanceWithin();

});

$(document).on('pagecreate', '#page1', function() {

    $("#log").on('click', function(){

        $.ajax({
            url: "script.login",
                type: "GET",
                data: { 'page':'create_user', 'access':'user','username':$("input[name='username']").val(), 'password':$("input[name='password']").val()},
                dataType: "text",
                success: function (html) {
                    console.log(html);


                    widgetNames = new Array();
                    widgetId = new Array();
                    var res = html.match(/insertNewChild(.*);/g);




                    for(var i =0;i<res.length;i++){

                        var temp = res[i].split(',');
                        if(temp.length >= 3){
                          widgetNames[i] = (temp[2].replace('");','')).replace('"','');
                          widgetId[i] = temp[1].replace("'","").replace("'","").replace(/ /g,'');
                        }           
                    }



                    var AllWidgets = ''


                    var testwidget = new Array();


                    var tempWidgetContent = html.match(/w\d+\.isHidden(.*)\(\) == false\)[\s\S]*?catch\(err\)\{ \}/gm);

                    for(var i =0;i<tempWidgetContent.length;i++){
                          var widgetContent = tempWidgetContent[i].substring(tempWidgetContent[i].indexOf('{')+1);

                          testwidget[i] = widgetContent.replace("site +","");


                    }



                  var widgetPart =  new Array();



                    for(var i = 0; i<widgetNames.length; i++){


                       var pageHeaderPart = "<div data-role='page' id='"+widgetId[i]+"' data-pageindex='"+i+"' class='dynPageClass'><div data-role='header' data-position='fixed'><a data-iconpos='notext' href='#panel' data-role='button' data-icon='flat-menu'></a><h1>BASKETBALL FANATICO</h1><a data-iconpos='notext' href='#page2' data-role='button' data-icon='home' title='Home'>Home</a></div> <div data-role='content'>";

                       var pageFooterPart = "</div><div data-role='footer' data-position='fixed'><span class='ui-title'><div id='navigator'></div></span></div></div>";

                        widgetPart[i] = '<DIV style=\" text-align: center; font-size: 100pt;\" id=widgetContainer_'+widgetId[i]+'></DIV><SCRIPT>' + 'function UpdateWidgetDiv'+widgetId[i]+'() {' + testwidget[i] + '$(\"#widgetContainer_'+widgetId[i]+'").html(counterValue);' + '}' + 'setInterval(function(){UpdateWidgetDiv'+widgetId[i]+'()},3000)' + '</SCRIPT>';




                  AllWidgets +='<a href="#'+widgetId[i]+'" class="widgetLink" data-theme="b" data-role="button" >'+widgetNames[i]+'</a>';                         


                                   var makePage = $(pageHeaderPart + widgetPart[i] + pageFooterPart);

                        makePage.appendTo($.mobile.pageContainer);
                    }
                    $('#items').prepend(AllWidgets).trigger('create');

                    var page = $('body').pagecontainer('getActivePage').prop("id");  

                    console.log('The Page Id is: '+page);

                }
        });
    });
});
```

In this code i am looking to run the following function

> 'setInterval(function(){UpdateWidgetDiv'+widgetId[i]+'()},3000)'

only for the page the user is viewing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/aCQ7u/)**

When creating the pages, as well as saving the page ids in the widgetId array, I am also saving the current page index as a data attribute on each dynamic page (data-pageindex), and I am assigning a class to all the dynamic pages (dynPageClass):

```
for (var i = 0; i< 3; i++){
    var pageid = 'dynPage' + i;
    widgetId.push(pageid);
    var p = '<div data-role="page" id="' + pageid + '" data-pageindex="' + i + '" class="dynPageClass">';
    p += '<div data-role="header"><h1>Dyn Page' + i + '</h1></div>';
    p += '<div role="main" class="ui-content">I am dynamically created</div>';
    p += '<div data-role="footer"><h1>Footer</h1></div>';
    p += '</div>';
    $('body').append($(p));
}
```

The the swipe code can be handled with one handler on the dynPageClass that handles both swipeleft and swiperight:

```
$(document).on("swiperight swipeleft", ".dynPageClass", function(e) {
    var ind = parseInt($(this).data('pageindex'));
    var topageid = "page2";
    var rev = true;
    if (e.type == 'swiperight'){
        if (ind > 0){
            topageid = widgetId[ind - 1] ; 
        }
    } else {
        rev = false;
        if (ind < widgetId.length - 1){
            topageid = widgetId[ind + 1] ; 
        }            
    }
    $.mobile.changePage("#" + topageid, {transition: "slide", reverse: rev});
});
```

We first get the current page's index from the data attribute and parse it into an integer. Then we see if this is a right or left swipe. If right, and index is greater than 0, we need to go back one dynamic page. Otherwise it is a left swipe and if current page is not the last one, we need to go forward one page.

Your swipeleft code on page2 is left intact:

```
$(document).on("swipeleft", "#page2", function() {
   $.mobile.changePage("#"+widgetId[0], {transition: "slide", reverse: false});
});
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your response. I have a slight problem when i tried your approach it seems that no matter which dynamic page i go to when i swipe it brings me back to the welcome page. i am putting up what i tried using you approach.

Comment: I put my code under my question. what am i missing in it? i used a dynamic class as u suggested.

Comment: You missed the data attribute (data-pageindex="' + i + '"), which lets us determine the current pages index.

Comment: Hey just another question for some reason when i swipe mine keeps going from page 2 to the first dynamically created page and back to page 2 automatically. i want it to stay on the dynamic page.

Comment: DO you mean the next time you swipe it goes back instead of forwards, or do you mean it jumps back immediately without swiping? Does my fiddle do that? Maybe you can reproduce the issue in a fiddle?

Comment: Sorry about my wording. What i mean is once i login i am on the welcome screen and then as i swipe left to go to the first dynamically generated page it goes to the dynamically generated page and then goes back to the welcome screen instead of stopping at the dynamically generated page. I hope that made sense.

Comment: The js fiddle you provided does not do that. so its probably to do with my code. should i post my code under my question?

Comment: You could post the code as an update to question, or just create or update my fiddle to reproduce the problem and post the link.

Comment: i have just posted the updated code. thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Looks like you are missing some quotes when building the page markup. Should be $("<div data-role='page' id='"+widgetId[i]+"' data-pageindex='"+i+"' class... (see extra single quotes for id and data-pageindex.  I put that into my fiddle and it works fine...

Comment: Hey, i just posted another question , wondering if you can help out maybe as you seem to have deep knowledge of jquery mobile. Thanks.

Comment: hey , i just edited this question as i am facing a slightly different issue .can you please help me? thanks

Comment: var page = $(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('getActivePage').prop("id"); or $('body').pagecontainer('getActivePage').prop("id"); will give you the id of the currently active page.

Comment: where would i place this code? before they dynamic pages are created or after? because i basically get id of currently active page from this and i pass it in my set interval function

Comment: testwidget[i] +=    "         setInterval(function(){UpdateWidgetDiv"+widgetId[i]+"()},3000)";

That is how i have my update function if u look in the code i posted above is the very last line.

Comment: so should i define this elsewhere seprately? and push in the active page id in to it?

Comment: have one setInterval function that always runs and tests which page is active and updates that page

Comment: That makes sense . but i just used your code and and i try to print the active page id in console log i get undefined. i just posted my entire script and commented the part where i have put ur code. is it wrong?

Comment: it is running too soon, put inside a pageshow event or somewhere after the pages have loaded.

Comment: yea it is actually placed right after the dynamic pages have been loaded.

Comment: no, it is outside of the pagecreate event so it runs before.

Comment: Yea you are right. when i placed it inside page create it gave me current page id.

Comment: hey, i managed to get my parsing working by so many trials and error but now i am facing a new error i suspect this is a small error can u please take a look i have posted in question section.

Comment: '$(\"#widgetContainer_'+widgetId[i]+') is missing a closing double quote ("): should be '$(\"#widgetContainer_'+widgetId[i]+'\")

Comment: on point thanks so much i will give you vote up on your answers to others questions.

Comment: Hey i was wondering if you can help me with the issue i just posted. i tried your way of trying to get active id and running my update function only on active pages but its not working. can u suggest how i can do this?

Comment: setInterval(UpdateWidgets, 3000);

function UpdateWidgets(){
    var activePage = $('body').pagecontainer('getActivePage').prop("id");
    //update the correct widget
}

Comment: The comment you there is correct. If you have control of the server code, on refresh return an array of the rows with updates, then iterate the array and updated the corresponding cells in the datatable.